# Why does 'scent' here use the singular form?

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammatical-number

> Flowers are chosen for their scent as well as their look.

In the above sentence, since these are countable nouns, shouldn't it say 'scents' and 'looks' instead of 'scent' and 'look'?

[image: Image of Collins dictionary page for scent]

Comment: Each type of flower has a single scent and look.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is fine. But  English does not adhere to strict logical consistency—no natural language does. But there **is** some consistency here, namely that attributes are expressed in the singular in the kind of genitive (possessive) usage you ask about. Compare to

> In our “lookist” culture, **women are** often judged by **their age** and **appearance**.
>
> Nearly all **employees** want to be judged by their **performance**.

Note too that the names of many such attributes are used as non-count nouns (*Cookie* is a count noun, *milk* is not: *many cookies* but *much milk*).

And there’s further logic, as @Barmar has commented. In my examples, each woman has her own age and appearance, each employee their own performance. So that does—at least partially—justify the singular.

Comment: As an extension, if employees are judged by their performances, it ascribes more than one performance or measure of performance to each employee. That *also* applies to "ages and appearances" in the first example; but since someone can only have one age and one [general] appearance, the meaning has to be interpreted as singular. Ambiguity is actually avoided by using the singular for each person.